# sshj executing script using nohup

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, sshj

I need to execute a shell script via sshj and disconnect without waiting for the script to complete.  The script can take a long time to complete, so I will be creating additional Java code to periodically check for results from the script.  How would do I disconnect the sshj session without waiting for the shell script to complete?

Answer (score 2):

End your command with `&`.  Example:

```
nohup /usr/bin/longRunningProcess &
```

Once that command is submitted (eg, submit the command and then call `Command.join()`), you can disconnect, and `longRunningProcess` will continue in the background.  The other thing to worry about is the command's output.  You will have to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` elsewhere, such as a file of `/dev/null`.  So, the command will look something like this:

```
nohup /usr/bin/longRunningProcess > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

And the Java code would be something like:

```
SSHClient client = ...
Session session = ...
Command command = session.exec(yourCommand);

// Wait for command to be submitted
command.join();

// Do some error checking by checking command.getExitStatus()
...

// Disconnect
session.close();
client.close();
```